# Passphrase for ssh keypair '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/lab-3-key' - AWS, ParallelCluster, FDS, Cloud9

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I am attempting to run FDS (CFD code for fire simulation) on Cloud9 pcluster using the following tutorial:
https://fds-smv-on-pcluster.workshop.aws/oyo/setup/pcluster.html

Basically, you install ParallelCluster, create a new keypair, write a configuration file and then create the pcluster, then download FDS to the cluster and use Slurm to submit the job.

A few of the input commands in the tutorial are out of date, but **I have gotten to the point where you connect to the PCluster with your created ssh lab key in order to download and install FDS software**:

```
pcluster ssh --cluster-name pc-fsx -i ~/.ssh/lab-3-key
```

And **I get asked for a passphrase:**

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/lab-3-key':
```

I do not know what this passphrase is.  Is it created when I create my lab key?  Is it from my AWS account or Cloud9 environment?  I am relatively new to AWS and Python.
I tried AWS password, name of key, blank/no password, no luck.

FYI, **the key is created as follows**:

```
IFACE=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/)
SUBNET_ID=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/${IFACE}/subnet-id)
VPC_ID=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/${IFACE}/vpc-id)
REGION=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//')
AWS_REGION=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//')
```

```
# generate a new key-pair
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name lab-3-your-key --query KeyMaterial --output text --region=${AWS_REGION} > ~/.ssh/lab-3-key
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/lab-3-key
```

I believe I did everything as the tutorial asked, as far as I could tell.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The passphrase is the phrase that you entered when you generated the key pair with the command

```
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name lab-3-your-key --query KeyMaterial --output text --region=${AWS_REGION} > ~/.ssh/lab-3-key
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't remember being prompted to enter a passphrase.  I tried your code and it creates a keypair but also doesn't prompt me to enter a passphrase.  Strangely, it doesn't output any text either.  It seems I wasn't aware of all the variables when creating the keypair.  Also, there is a new tutorial for FDS on AWS ParallelCluster here:https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/fire-dynamics-simulation-cfd-workflow-using-aws-parallelcluster-elastic-fabric-adapter-amazon-fsx-for-lustre-and-nice-dcv/.  I have gotten farther with this tutorial so I think it is more intuitive.